# Error on encoding '?' to '%3F' in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I have an URL such as

```
bulkmessaging/public/pdf/messagereport_pdf.php
```

Now I'm appending a query string, for example:

```
bulkmessaging/public/pdf/messagereport_pdf.php?company="+company+"&user="+user+"&reportfor="+reportfor+"
```

I want to download a PDF on redirecting this path but when I redirect this path `?` is encoded to `%3F` in Google Chrome and I'm not getting the PDF. The code is working fine with Mozilla Firefox. It should remain `?` only in the URL when redirecting using Chrome.

```
location.pathname = "bulkmessaging/public/pdf/messagereport_pdf.php?company="+company+"&user="+user+"&reportfor="+reportfor+"";
```

This is the code in Javascript from where I am redirecting the PDF file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show part of the code that creates and redirects to that url

Comment: location.pathname = "bulkmessaging/public/pdf/messagereport_pdf.php?company="+company+"&user="+user+"&reportfor="+reportfor+"";                                               This is the code in javascript from where im redirecting

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `location.pathname` to do the redirect to the PDF, you should use `window.location`:

```
window.location = "bulkmessaging/public/pdf/messagereport_pdf.php?company="+company+"&user="+user+"&reportfor="+reportfor+"";
```

Comment: Thanks @Niraj Shah this sorted me out